# h:outputText inside of href doesn't work in JSF 2.0

Tags: xhtml, jsf-2

I'm migrating code from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0(deployed on JBoss 6.1). However, I am experiencing problem with using `h:outputText` inside of `href` attribute of `link` tag:

```
<link rel='canonical' href='<h:outputText value="#{resultPage.currentLink}" escape="false"/>' />
```

I cannot just use

```
<link rel='canonical' href="#{resultPage.currentLink}" />
```

because I need html escape attribute.

I'm receiving the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /shoe/shoe2.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 23] The value of attribute "href" associated with an element type "link" must not contain the '<' character.
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
    com.youandshoe.web.controller.EncoderFilter.doFilter(EncoderFilter.java:28)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:126)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)

root cause

javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /shoe/shoe2.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 23] The value of attribute "href" associated with an element type "link" must not contain the '<' character.
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:390)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:373)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.metadataCompile(Compiler.java:128)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:316)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$200(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:89)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:165)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:164)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:90)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:86)
    com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:95)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:110)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:58)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:249)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:198)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:223)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:107)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.execute(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:97)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    com.youandshoe.web.controller.EncoderFilter.doFilter(EncoderFilter.java:28)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:126)
    com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)
```

However, the same code works fine in JSF 1.2, JBoss 5.1.

Any ideas? Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facelets is a XML based view technology. The XML document must be well-formed. Nesting XML tags is invalid. To fix your problem, you'd need to include the whole HTML inside the `<h:outputText>` instead.

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;link rel=&quot;canonical&quot; href=&quot;#{resultPage.currentLink}&quot; /&gt;" escape="false" />
```

By the way, I really wonder why you can't just use

```
<link rel="canonical" href="#{resultPage.currentLink}" />
```

That should work equally fine. Having XML special characters in `href` attribute would otherwise result in invalid XML markup errors in the browser side anyway and the browser won't be able to download the resource.

Comment: Btw if I use <link rel="canonical" href="#{resultPage.currentLink}" />
, href value wouldn't be like "...keywords=nike&page=1&pages=83", but "...keywords=nike&amp;page=1&amp;pages=83". Framework (or browser?) encodes '&' characters into '&amp;', which creates invalid link.

Comment: Sorry, wrong formulation, it is not invalid, but in the format I don't prefer. I don't want to have "keywords=nike&amp;page=1&amp;pages=83" in the link, but "keywords=nike&page=1&pages=83".

Comment: Why don't you prefer that? It works equally good. Why doing different than anyone else and trying the hard way because *you* want to do it differently?

Comment: It works good (if you click on generated link and open in in browser), but I'm not sure if this can make problems when Google crawler visit my site and, instead of <meta name="keywords" content="D&G , Dolce&Gabbana">, it finds <meta name="keywords" content="D&amp;G , Dolce&amp;Gabbana">.

Comment: Google would be stupid if it didn't follow the web standards. W3 requires predefinied HTML/XML entities to be delivered in escaped form.